# Nuxtjs plugin registration

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

I am curious as to the methodology Nuxt.js uses to register a plugin. I have been reading the documentation for Nuxt.js and I am slightly confused as to the registration methodology.

I **do not** want to register plugins such as `vue-flag-icon` globally.

My understanding is when we register the plugin we use the plugin folder as such:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import FlagIcon from 'vue-flag-icon'


Vue.use(FlagIcon)
```

I can now use the flag component anywhere in my app - I dont want this!!!

I want to be able to load plugins into the components that need them ONLY.

I have tried loading them as a component like:

```
components:{
 'flag': ()=> import('path to plugin') // @/plugins/vue-flag-icon
}
```

This does not work.

I changed my plugins script to:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import FlagIcon from 'vue-flag-icon'

export default () => {
  Vue.use(FlagIcon)
}
```

And then tried to register the plugin  within the components like so:

```
   import flag from '@/plugins/vue-flag-icon';

    created(){
       flag()
   }
```

My questions really are:

1. How can I register a plugin within the component without importing the `vue` instance? (I think is called a bus)
2. Is it bad practice to import the plugins directly into components?
3. Is registering all the plugins within `nuxt.config.js` creating a larger download file for users to download (example: registering vue-twix is not necessary on pages that do not have textareas) or will nuxt/webpack handle the removal of unnecessary plugins on a page by page or component by component basis (so I don't have to even worry about this)?. If this is the case than I dig nuxt.

Thanks

Comment: Whats wrong with the `components` one? Any errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use FlagIcon only on certain components, you have to import it and use it on every component you want to use.

```
<template>
  <flag iso="ca" />
</template>

<script>
import FlagIcon from 'vue-flag-icon'
export default () => {
  components: {
    FlagIcon
  }
</script>
```

This should work.

For other components, remember to import any style sheets the component might require:

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
  @import 'path/to/plugin/style.css';
</style>
```

Comment: It is. There's simply no good reason why creating a plugin and calling that from the component as opposed to simply import the component inside the component that's going to use it. Specially not in the case mentioned (vue-flag-icon).

Nuxt plugins are used to inject components into Vue, kind of like on a regular vue-cli application you'd do in the main.js file.